# Build fails while running AppManifestCleanupUtil executable for Service Fabric App

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

As part of my service fabric application, my ApplicationManifest.xml is under source control with the rest of my code.When the build runs on the build server, it fails with the below exception.This  occurs during the execution of AppManifestCleanupUtil while updating the ApplicationManifest. It works just fine on my machine. Am i missing something here ? -

```
Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\MyProject\ApplicationManifest.xml' is denied.
```

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Common.ExclusiveFileStream.Acquire(String path, FileMode fileMode, FileShare fileShare)
   at AppManifestCleanupUtil.AppManifestCleanupUtil.LoadExistingAppManifest(String appManifestPath)
   at AppManifestCleanupUtil.AppManifestCleanupUtil.CleanUp(String appManifestPath, List`1 serviceManifestPaths, List`1 appParamFilePaths)
   at AppManifestCleanupUtil.Program.Main(String[] args)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to build locally on your development machine prior to submitting to source control.  That will ensure the ApplicationManifest.xml file is up-to-date with your application project state.  If it is not up-to-date and the file is read-only, you'll get this error.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Thalman, I did but the issue is that even if there is a spacing issues the content match fails in the Clean up Utility and it tries to update. I am not sure with a big team of Devs in our project, how feasible it is .

Comment: Should this validation not be limited to the actual elements/content. Json is frequently used these days for Configuration (Cluster manifest allows it). Can Service /App manifest not be a Json instead to make it easier to parse and validate ?